# How to stream multiple video files with wowza

Tags: stream, wowza

I am trying to play multiple files in one playlist with the wowza streaming server. I thought that I can manage this functionality with a SMIL file, but that didn't work either.

I don't know whether wowza is using the smil file only for bitrate swithing but the sequence didnt work for me.

The smil file is looking like this:

```
<smil>
<head></head>
<body>
    <seq>
        <video src="mp4:test1.mp4" system-bitrate="600000"></video>
        <video src="mp4:test2.mp4" system-bitrate="600000"></video>
    </seq>
</body>
```

When I replace the sequence tag with a switch tag, it only plays the second video and not the first one at all.

Is it even possible to create such stream where I will be able to play multiple video files defined in a smil file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

from what I know, Wowza does not allow to join separate files into a single VOD stream.
i was building kind of special streaming proxy server for such purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have also read it unfortunately in the help-right-side-bar and didn't find any reference on that matter. Do you have any idea how to create such stream?

Comment: generally you'll need to build streaming proxy server :) that will create playlists on-the-fly and proxy chunks requests to different streams available on Wowza. so that will be kind of imitation of single stream for end user, and Wowza will just server 2 files as it usually serves.

Comment: hi @rshmelev could you write detailed steps how to do that, I'm facing the same problem